# Lambda Calculus - Exercise with fixed point combinator

Tags: proof-verification, logic, alternative-proof, lambda-calculus

This is exercise *2.10(iii)* from ["Introduction to Lambda Calculus"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/logic/TypesSS05/Extra/geuvers.pdf). We need to find an $F$ such that $F \mathbf{I} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{K} = F \mathbf{K}$

Here there is my solution:

> Let $\mathbf{K}_3 \equiv \lambda xyabz.xyz$ and let $F \equiv \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3$. We have that 
>   $$\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{K}_3 = \mathbf{K}_3 (\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3) =
> (\lambda xyabz.xyz)\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3 =
>  \lambda abz. \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3 z.$$
>
> Thus, $F \mathbf{I} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{K}=(\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3)\mathbf{I} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{K} = (\lambda abz. \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3 z) \mathbf{I} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{K} = (\lambda z. \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3 z) \mathbf{K} = \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{K}_3  \mathbf{K} = F \mathbf{K}$.

I think it is correct, but I am really not sure for three reasons:

1. it really looks ugly;
2. it is not 'unique', since $\mathbf{K}_3$ can be alternatively defined as $\mathbf{K}_3 \equiv \lambda xyazb.xyz$;
3. it is completely independent from the combinators, since it can work for any term.

Are my concerns correct?
Is the solution correct?
If it is, is there a more pleasing solution?
If not, what's wrong with it?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

PS: Of course, $\mathbf{K}_3$ is just the name I gave to that term (i.e., it is not official).

Comment: Regarding 1: It's lambda calculus, everything looks ugly :P Regarding 2: You can realize just by looking at the equation that whatever F is, it can have at least two definitions just by switching second and third parameter. So I wouldn't worry about that. I don't know if that is the expected solution, but it is a good one